How to calculate Term Deposit Redemption Rate (TDDR)?
How would you estimate Term Deposit Redemption Rate (TDRR) in the context of regulatory banking (IRRBB and ALM)?
Supose I have a database with net balance of term deposits (1), early redemptions (2) and  new investiments (3). I could not find any suggestion in regulatory documents (Basel, EBA and so on).
I would suggest calculating it by the ratio of 2/(1+3). Any thoughts?
